# Save Android WebView cache as Data Storage

Tags: android, android-webview

In remote webapp wrapped in a `WebView`, I enter the webapp, and then thereby--via the appropriate `WebSettings`--cache the webapp. When I start the app offline, I receive all the cached files. Life is good.

However, if you clear the application's cache via the [clear all cache option](http://cdn2.ubergizmo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/asdasdf-640x533.jpg)--which a user would use to regain some space on their device--then your webapp is no longer available while offline.

A way around this--apart from storing the entire webapp in your APK--would be to save the cache in the app's 'data' storage. This means the 'clear all cache' operation would not destroy the cached webapp.

Is saving the cache to 'data' storage possible?